# How to add Content Assist to text field in Wizard using SWT java

Tags: java, swt, jface, wizard

I have designed a wizard page with a text field using SWT. I want to add a content assist to the text field i.e , when i press 'Ctrl+space', it has to propose the list of data. Any  standard method to implement this feature?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works.  Questions of the form _"I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code"_ are considered off-topic.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the JFace `ContentProposalAdapter` to do this on a `Text` control.

Use something like:

```
Text textControl = ....


KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getInstance("Ctrl+Space");

new ContentProposalAdapter(textControl, new TextContentAdapter(), provider, keyStroke, null);
```

`provider` is a class implementing `IContentProposalProvider` this just has one method `getProposals`:

```
@Override
public IContentProposal [] getProposals(String contents, int position)
{
  // TODO return array of `ContentProposal` objects appropriate to the contents
}
```

Comment: is there a way using EMF modeling and data binding to get this content assist ? where we use textviewer .

Comment: TextViewer is completely different to Text. Ask a new question

Comment: I am unable to ask question as they have banned me from asking questions. Could you please help me here

Comment: I don't use EMF