# Triger the ContentAssistant in java

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I need to add a content assistant to an editor in Java. I have found some material [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_Content_Assist_to_my_editor%3F).

However I don't understand how can I trigger the content assistant. I have a class that implemented the method getContentAssistant, but I don't know how to call it.

Comment: So have you set it up in the source viewer as described in that link? Does it work with the standard Ctrl+Space trigger for content assist?

Comment: Yes, I set up a source viewer, but ctrl space does not trigger anything.

Comment: In that link, they create an action, I don't really understand how to use that action and call getContentAssistant.

Comment: It looks like AbstractTextEditor createActions does actually set up ContentAssistAction itself so that part of the document is probably out of date. Something needs to set up the Ctrl+Space key binding and the content assist command - not sure what does that.

Comment: Manage to do it using ContentProposalAdapter like in this post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42687493/how-to-add-content-assist-to-text-field-in-wizard-using-swt-java

Comment: This post was helpful: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42687493/how-to-add-content-assist-to-text-field-in-wizard-using-swt-java).
I used ContentProposalAdapter.